# How can I achieve this effect on my text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography

I have recently scattered through the portfolio of a designer named Nicolas Girard, and noticed this fascinating typography art:

[image]

I looked through the entire web and in every Photoshop and Illustrator tutorials site I know and tried to find an explanation to something somewhat similar to this text effect but I could not find anything...

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this Diagonal-Lines-Gradient-Effect on my text?
I am using Adobe Photoshop & Illustrator, both CS5, and I have a bit more than basic knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: Create rectangles of varying widths. Give each a gradient using colors along the spectrum. Skew it 45 degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a little extra, so as far as creating those gradient lines go.. this is a <sub>little</sub> over the top and under the bridge and beside the waterfall...

[Link to img
[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVOal.jpg)

<sub>Lol, noticed I made a typo in my name... Wweeell.. it's still a morning and whatevs..</sub>

[Link to .Psd file.](http://www.photoshopmesta.net/1/jp.psd) <sub>( By the way.. apparently chrome doesn't allow downloading of psd files.. or something.. use FireFox.. )</sub>

In Photoshop

1. Make the text
2. Apply the proper `Layer styles` from `Blending options` <sub>( You can get there by right clicking the text layer and selecting it from the list. )</sub>
3. Make a group ( Above text layer ) Then make a selection from the text by clicking text layer thumbnail while pressing (`Ctrl`). Once selected click Layer mask icon at the bottom of the `Layers` panel.
4. **The Diagonal lines** - Inside the group make a new layer (`Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N`). With `Polygonal Lasso Tool` (`L`) while holding (`Shift`) button make a selection where the left side is at 45 degree angle, rest of the selection doesn't matter.. just make it big enough so that you have something to era.. Try to make a selection that is about 45 degrees and because you are holding shift, the selection will be exactly 45 degrees.
5. Fill that with white color and `Deselect` (`Ctrl+D`)
6. Use `Eraser Tool` (`E`) With Soft round brush of different sizes to soften out the right side of that white area ( watch out for the left side.. but in some cases you might want to go over it a little bit to make the edge tad uneven.. )
7. Apply `Blend mode: Overlay` to the layer and replicate everything starting from 4. a *few* times.
8. After you have done a few more that are slightly different `Duplicate` these layers one by one (`Ctrl+J`) and move with `Move Tool` (`V`) while holding (`Shift`) if necessary..
9. After that I basically just copied the whole Group ( right click and Duplicate ) and moved the position of those white highlights and gave the group below a lower `opacity`
10. **Some extra stuff** I selected every layer minus background with (`Ctrl` or `Shift`) and merged them into a new layer (`Ctrl+Alt+E`). Then gave it `Filter > Sketch > Chrome` and after that gave it `Blend mode: Screen` and lowered the opacity just a little.
11. Then I selected everything once again.. ( minus the same things ) and merged them into a new layer just like before. Then `Edit > Transform > Flip Vertical` and moved it below my original text in the document and used `Eraser Tool` with soft round brush again to erase the bottom part of the text.
12. Theen I made a new layer and in it a white rectangle and used `Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur..` in it and gave it the `Blend mode: Overlay` and copied it once (`Ctrl+J`)
13. Theeen I made the sparkles and swoosh swoosh...

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I'm going to try it right up!

Comment: @iLyrical If there's anything in my writing that doesn't make sense.. just tell me and I can fix it... I wrote this in the morning when I wasn't exactly awake yet.. and I haven't read it through yet.